# Querying dbpedia, not getting expected result not sure what's the mistake

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

My query is

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?craft where
{
  ?craft <http://dbpedia.org/property/title> ?v.
}
```

Now this returning lot of results,
but nothing related to Steve Jobs or Tim Cook, even though in their page there is a property named title.

- `dbp:title dbr:List_of_Apple_Computer_CEOs`
- http://dbpedia.org/page/Steve_Jobs

Comment: Asked same question at https://dbpedia.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DBP/customcontent/238125057 ... now both are cross-linked

Answer (score 1):

The query:

```sql
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?nb_result)
WHERE {
    ?craft dbp:title ?v .
}
```

returns:

```sql
nb_result
---------
1566113
```

The public query endpoint for DBpedia [limits the number of results to 10,000, among other restrictions](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/dbpedia-usage-report-as-of-2018-01-01-8cae1b81ca71). So your  chances of retrieving any specific statement there are very small. If you worry that the data at the query endpoint is different than at the front end, you can check that the data is there with the query:

```sql
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?prop ?value
WHERE {
    dbr:Steve_Jobs ?prop ?value .
}
```

and compare with what's displayed at http://dbpedia.org/page/Steve_Jobs.

Comment: Ohkay thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of the fact that query limit of 10000.